# SQLITE Error on Android: No such table XXXXXX

Tags: android, sqlite, jquery-mobile

I have this line of codes here showing database table being created. There are two problems I have observed when I run the project. First is the thrown error: **No such table patients** when I button click the save button.  Second was the function _populate. It doesn't populate the listview. Is it because in the first place, the program didn't create the database/tables? What may be wrong with it?

```
var database = window.openDatabase("nurse", "1.0", "Nurse DB", 1000000);
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log("Ready.");
    database.transaction(_tableCreate, onSuccess, onError);
    database.transaction(_populate, onSuccess, onError);

    init();
    $('#_interventions').on('pageshow', $showInterventions);
}

function onSuccess(i) {
    console.log("Yay! " + i.code + ': ' + i.message);
}

function onError(err) {
    console.log("Oh dear. " + err);
}

function _tableCreate(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "category"("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL CHECK("id">=0));');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "diagnoses"("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL CHECK("id">=0), "name" VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, "category" INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK("category">=0), CONSTRAINT "FKdiag_category" FOREIGN KEY("category") REFERENCES "category"("id"));');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "diagnoses.FKdiag_category_idx" ON "diagnoses"("category");');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "interventions"("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL CHECK("id">=0), "action" TEXT NOT NULL, "priority" TEXT NOT NULL CHECK("priority" IN(\'1\',\'2\',\'3\',\'4\',\'5\')), "category" INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK("category">=0), CONSTRAINT "FKintervention_category" FOREIGN KEY("category") REFERENCES "category"("id"));');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "interventions.FKintervention_category_idx" ON "interventions"("category");');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "patients"("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL CHECK("id">=0), "name" VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, "age" INTEGER NOT NULL, "intervention" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, "subjective" VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL, "objective" VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL, "assessment" VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL, "planning" VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL, "evaluation" VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL);');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "analysis"("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL CHECK("id">=0), "patient" INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK("patient">=0), "interventions" VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT NULL, CONSTRAINT "FKanalysis_patient" FOREIGN KEY("patient") REFERENCES "patients"("id"));');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "analysis.FKanalysis_patient_idx" ON "analysis"("patient");');
}

function _populate(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM category', [], function(tx, results) {
        var count = results.rows.item(0).count;
        if (count > 0) {
            console.log("Found existing records.");
            console.log(count + " items.");
            return;
        } else {
            console.log("Starting with fresh installation.");
            $.ajax({
                async: false,
                url: "file:///android_asset/www/dev/data.sql",
                type: 'GET'
            }).done(function(data) {
                console.log('Data found!');
                var sql = data.split("@@@@@");
                for (var i = 0; i < sql.length; i++) {
                    if (sql[i] !== '') {
//                        console.log("Executing: " + sql[i]);
                        tx.executeSql(sql[i]);
                    }
                }
                console.log('Finished recording data.');
            }).fail(onError);
        }
    }, onError);
}
```

Comment: Well, your tables simply aren't created. Put in some logging and check the errors.

Comment: put this database = window.openDatabase("nurse", "1.0", "Nurse DB", 1000000); inside onDeviceReady function and try..